# Tensorflow loading saved models yields a very high cost value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save a Tensorflow model and reuse it.

To clearly understand the issue I have created a binary data set with 10 elements and run the training on this 10 elements repeatedly whereas I save the model every 100 iterations. 
Then run the test on the same set. Ideally I would expect the test to yield the same cost by the time the model was saved.
However probably I miss something and loading a trained model doesn't give the expected cost value:

```
def model(X, w1, w2, w3, w4, wo, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden):
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)
    # ... other layer def.s
    l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3, w4))
    l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)    
    return tf.matmul(l4, wo, name="pyx") 

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, size1, size2, size3], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1], name="Y")
py_x = model(X, wo, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x, targets=Y, pos_weight=POS_WEIGHT))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    batch_x, batch_y = read_file('train.dat', 10)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

    for step in range(NUM_TRAIN_BATCHES):
        x, y = sess.run([batch_x, batch_y])
        _, costval = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={X: x, Y: y, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
        if step % 100 == 0
            print("Step %d, cost %1.5f" % (step, cost_value))
            saver.save(sess, './train.model', global_step=step)
```

The above code prints below:

```
Step 0, cost 1.10902
Step 100, cost 0.83170
Step 200, cost 0.00003
Step 300, cost 0.00000
```

Now if I load model that saved during 300th iteration and try to apply to the same data:

```
model_no = 300
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./train.model-%d.meta' % (model_no))
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    batch_x, batch_y = read_file('train.dat', 10)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x, y = sess.run([batch_x, batch_y])
    cost_value = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={"X:0": x, "Y:0": y, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
    print("cost %1.5f" % (cost_value))
```

And the above prints:

```
cost loss 1.10895
```

which is very closed to the first iteration of the model training.

Also another thing I can't get my head around is the checkpoint file, which contains only below:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "train.model-300"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "train.model-0"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "train.model-100"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "train.model-200"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "train.model-300"
```

How does it help and what's the idea behind calling `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))` if the checkpoint only contains paths of model files and I explicitly load a particular model?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./train.model-%d.meta' % (model_no))
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    batch_x, batch_y = read_file('train.dat', 10)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # <------
```

You are re-initializing all variables, which means you are overwriting your loaded weights with random weights again. Either check first if you load something or start from scratch, or initialize first and then load. Or, use something like TF's supervisor that does the bookkeeping for you.

Comment: On a side note, for testing, you usually want to set the keep probability of all dropout layers to 1.

Comment: OK, I've moved     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  before saver = .. line and the cost is still 1.10919

Comment: There's nothing else obvious, except for the lack of random sampling in training. Are you sure your data is properly randomized?

Comment: Oh, and in a setup like this (separate test script) there's no need for the init at all - all vars needed for inference should be in the snapshot. The mixed init/restore is typically in training scripts that you can restart and they continue ...

Comment: My data set is really very limited (only 10 elements) so I really don't think there is a randomisation issue (I hope). Also removing "sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())" yields an error.